# CountIF using if statement in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to look at the values in 2 columns and if they meet certain criteria, I then want to count the number of times a value is there.

For instance, in range `F3:F250` I want to look for the letters "H2O". Then in range `G3:G250` I want to look for the letters "MW". If both these conditions are met, I want to count the number of times "MW" appears.

My current formula;

`=IF($F$3:$F$250="H2O",IF($G$2:G$250="MW",COUNTIF($G$3:$G$250‌​,"MW"),0))`

Comment: You'll get better response if you explain what you've already tried.

Comment: =IF($F$3:$F$250="H2O",IF($G$2:G$250="MW",COUNTIF($G$3:$G$250,"MW"),0))

Comment: I don't get why you want to count the number of times MW appears, in stead of just counting the rows in which they appear both. Can MW appear multiple times in a single row?

Comment: @NigelBennett In order to fully understand your problem, we could use a snippet of the columns themselves.  Can you add that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CountIFs() for this.  Try:

```
=COUNTIFS(F3:F250,"H2O", G2:G250,"MW")
```

Comment: This is the simple, easy solution to the problem as stated.  I don't know why someone would vote it down.  I'm going to vote it back up.  Sheesh, I sympathize, @uSlackr.

Comment: Maybe they wanted a link to more information about COUNTIFS().  That can be found on [this help page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842).

Comment: I don't think this does exactly what is asked to be fair. I'm trying it right now, and unless the ranges are next to each other `F3:F250,"H2O", G3:G250,"MW"` rather than `F3:F250,"H2O", G2:G250,"MW"` it will just return `#Value`. It also only counts when "H2O" and "MW" is on the same row, which I can't see as a criteria in the question.

Comment: The way I read his intro paragraph, he wants to count based on two parameters, not one.  That's the solution I proposed. He question is unclear but at least one other person agrees with me. If you read the question differently, propose your own answer. I've asked the OP for a snippet so we will know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the thing to count is the same as one of the criterias, which should simplify things.
In the question however, you only say:
*"if they meet certain criteria, I then want to count the number of times a value is there."*
Not that the value necessarily is one of the criterias.

In that case, something like this should work:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F3:F250,"X")>0,IF(COUNTIF(G3:G250,"Y")>0,COUNTIF(G3:G250,"Z"),"NO Y"),"NO X")
```

This will look for "X" *(your first value)* in column F, 
"Y" *(your second value)* in column G, and then count "Z" *(your third value, which may or may not be the same as previous values)* in column G.

Just change values accordingly, and add "$" if needed.

Note: I tried using `IF(F3:F250="X")` Instead of `COUNTIF(F3:F250,"X")` But it didn't behave consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using Match() and Countif():

```
=IF(MATCH("H2O",F3:F250,0),COUNTIF(G3:G250,"MW"),0)
```

Any match on H2O will cause a True condition and execute the Countif().  Otherwise, it will return a zero.